# Vue-router: No route works after build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

I created a project with Vite, Pinia and Vue-router. Everything works perfectly in development, but when I access the build, only the main path works. All other redirects return 404:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
"crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ VM10:6789"

Any idea what could be happening?

*** Main.js ***

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

// Font Awesome
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

//Router
import router from './router'

//Pinia
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import piniaPluginPersistedstate from 'pinia-plugin-persistedstate'

library.add(fas, far, fab);

const pinia = createPinia();
pinia.use(piniaPluginPersistedstate);

createApp(App)
.use(pinia)
.use(router)
.component('fa', FontAwesomeIcon)
.mount('#app')
```

*** App.vue ***

```
 <script setup>
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";


</script>

<template>
  <RouterView />
</template>
```

*** router/index.js ***

```
    import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import { useAuthStore } from '../stores/AuthStore';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [

        {
            path: "/katriumweb/login",
            name: "login",
            component: () => import("@/views/Login.vue")
        },
        {
            path: "/katriumweb/playground",
            name: "playground",
            component: () => import("@/views/Playground.vue")
        },
        {
            path: "/katriumweb/",
            name: "home",
            component: () => import("@/views/Home.vue"),
            meta: {
                authRequired: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/katriumweb/vehicleupdate",
            name: "vehicleupdate",
            component: () => import("@/views//workflows/VehicleUpdate.vue"),
            meta: {
                authRequired: true
            }
        }

    ],
});


router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {

    const authStore = useAuthStore();

    let token = authStore.user? authStore.user.TOKEN : false;
    
    const checkToken = await fetch("*******", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Token": `${token}`
        }
    })

    if (to.meta.authRequired) {
        if (!checkToken.ok || !token) {
            localStorage.clear();
            next("/katriumweb/login");
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
})


export default router;
```

*** vite.config.js ***

```
    import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/katriumweb/",
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I replaced createWebHistory with createWebHashHistory and it worked satisfactorily with the # preceding the parameter.

Comment: Your web server must always return the index.html on any route you define in the router. You need to configure your web server accordingly. Usually you just return the index.html on any URL except the ones with actual assets. You can circumvent that when you just use the hash.

Comment: See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the app itself only has an `index.html` file and everything else is done via javascript, when you navigate to `/mypage` it tries to grab another html file.
The Vue Router `createWebHistory` works this way. A simple fix is to use `createWebHashHistory`, which uses a hash in order to create the routing.

Otherwise, more solutions are available on the documentation (eg. Netlify supports a redirect property to handle this).

The docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html